# How to remove Python list items that start with a certain string without receiving AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, list

I have a list of hrefs that have been scraped from a URL using Python (sample provided below) From this list I wish to remove any lines that **do not start with** "/player/". The idea being that this will keep only the url links to players.

```
test = ['/england/afc-bournemouth-vs-luton-town-fc-h2h-stats',
 '/england/afc-bournemouth-vs-peterborough-united-fc-h2h-stats',
 None,
 '/players/england/dominic-solanke',
 '/players/england/jaidon-anthony',
 '/players/england/david-brooks',
 '/players/england/morgan-rogers',
 '/players/england/junior-stanislas',
 '/players/england/ben-pearson',
 '/players/england/jamal-lowe',
'/c-dl.php?type=matches&comp=6089',
 '/c-dl.php?type=matches&comp=6013'
]
```

I have tried the following code but receive this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

```
result = [i for i in test if i.startswith('/players/')]
```

I think this means my list items do not contain a string? Is there a way to convert to string or use an alternative method to remove the unwanted links from the list?

Thanks

Comment: `result = [i for i in test if i is not None and i.startswith('/players/')]` ...?

Comment: Your list contains a None. Just change the code to: result = [i for i in test if i and i.startswith('/players/')]

Comment: According to your description and code example you don't want to remove the strings starting with "/players/" from the existing list but you want to create a new list with those values. Please clarify.

Comment: @Matthias You are correct that I want to keep the strings with '/players'. I would be happy if that either removes any other strings OR moves the '/players' strings to a new list. Either method would allow me to continue my project

Comment: @NirH. Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks. Could you explain you mean by a "None" in my list. Is this an empty entry or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution was provided by @Nir H.

> Your list contains a None. Just change the code to: result = [i for i
> in test if i and i.startswith('/players/')]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).